# Codeigniter controller action routing issue

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am beginner in Codeigniter. 
In **.htaccess** file

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

In config.php file I have made changes as

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
$config['url_suffix'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

In route.php file I have made changes as

```
$route['products/register']  = 'products/register';
$route['products'] = 'products';
$route['default_controller'] = 'products';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Products Controller

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed'); 
class Products extends CI_Controller {  
  public function __construct(){  
       parent::__construct(); 
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation', 'email')); 
        $this->load->database();           
        $this->load->model("product_model");  
  }       
  public function index()  
  {  
         die("aaaaa"); exit;
  }  
  public function register()  
   {  
       die("DSds");
   }
 }
```

When I request url in browser http://localhost/codei/products/register its shows 404 Page Not Found

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Try the above code in .htaccess and also set base url in config file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codei/';
```

Comment: check rewrite_mode is on in apache (xampp or wamp)

Answer (score 0):

Use this it will definitely work for you.
Don't do anyting else all are perfect.
Only replace .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

> note: Make sure rewrite_mode is on in apache